# Как отследить периодические изменения на странице загруженной в WebBrowser

Tags: javascript, webbrowser

Подскажите, как отследить периодические изменения на странице загруженной в WebBrowser. 
На странице есть скрипт js вида:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://site.com/script.js></script>
<script type="text/javascript">func()</script>
```

Результат выполнения этого скрипта периодическое изменение куска текста на странице (без перерисовки страницы).
Как можно отследить изменение этого текста и передать текст в другое окно приложения?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Используйте отладчик используемого вами обзорщика.